# AMPHTML In Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html, content-builder

Google announced the ability to create interactive emails using an HTML framework known as AMPHTML (*not to be confused with AMPscript*). Here is some documentation if anyone is interested in learning more: [AMPHTML Docs](https://amp.dev/about/email.html)

I have reached out to Salesforce and they seem to not be able to support this out of content builder at the moment. I was wondering if anyone has found a viable workaround to be able to send these emails through our SFMC IP address and email domains. I was thinking about creating a custom activity route but seems very robust for just sending an HTML file!

Comment: As @EazyE stated in his answer, there is no way to add the MIME type in SFMC, but you can technically push in the AMPHTML, etc. inside the platform. It just will not be able to communicate the MIME type at send, meaning it will likely not be rendered as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would require SFMC servers to support a third MIME type. So there is not a way to send out of SFMC. You can help vote for the idea here ['Support Google AMP for Email or AMPHTML as a MIME version in Marketing Cloud'](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000ECheQAG)

Answer (score 0):

Seconded what EazyE has mentioned. SFMC will need an update to the mail processor to send this type of message. From what I've heard, don't expect it anytime soon.

I've been able to chat with some Salesforce product managers about interactivity in email, and it sounds like they have some different approaches to consider - see their [acquisition of Rebel](https://techcrunch.com/2018/10/05/salesforce-acquires-rebel-maker-of-interactive-email-services-to-expand-its-marketing-cloud/) - yet not the extent of AMP for email.

I'm very interested to see where this goes!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Marketing Cloud January 2021 Feature Overview AMP E-Mails will become available in the week of March 1st 2021.